# How to change attributes in a LinkButton Href asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello how can i change attributes inside a LinkButton, on button click event.

This is an example:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblBarcode" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxbBarcode"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblAltura" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxbAltura"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LBPrinter" href="print://1234/TxbBarcode/TxbAltura" OnClick="LBPrinter_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

How can i do that the information that is written in the textboxes gets inserted in the href?

Comment: I suppose you want to do this at client side? may be using JavaScript

Comment: @Bharat yes i do, and use that information

Comment: Below i have posted a small example.  Did that work?

Comment: @Bharat yes it did thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle client-side events, especially click we have an event handler **onclientclick**.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LBPrinter" href="print://1234/TxbBarcode/TxbAltura" OnClick="LBPrinter_Click" onclientclick='changeLink(this)'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Client-Side Javascript:

```
function changeLink(linkButton) {
  linkButton.href = "<new link>";
}
```